# How to connect Backstage to Kubernetes cluster to discover pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, backstage

I am trying to connect Backstage to a Kubernetes cluster deployed on EKS in order to discover pods and display them on the pages for their respective components. To connect to a cluster, Backstage needs a "cluster URL". Where can I find the cluster URL and port? Should I be able to connect to this cluster when running locally?

I am running Backstage locally on my machine and trying to connect to a deployed EKS cluster. Here is the configuration in my `app-config.yaml`:

```yaml
kubernetes:
  serviceLocatorMethod:
    type: 'multiTenant'
  clusterLocatorMethods:
    - type: 'config'
      clusters:
        - url: http://111.11.1.1:1111
          name: my-cluster-eks
          authProvider: 'aws'
          skipTLSVerify: true
          skipMetricsLookup: true

auth:
  environment: 'development'
  providers:
    aws:
      development:
        accessKeyId: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
        secretAccessKey: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run command `kubectl cluster-info` for your cluster.

it will look something like this:

```
kubectl cluster-info 

Kubernetes control plane is running at https://some-ip
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://some-ip1/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend:http/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://some-ip/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
KubeDNSUpstream is running at https://some-ip/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns-upstream:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://some-ip/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
```

Copy your Kubernetes control plane IP `https://some-ip` to your app-config.yaml and it should work